# New Line and Carriage Return Characters not Processed in XSLT Value-Of

Tags: xml, xslt, newline, carriage-return

I have the following basic XSLT code where I try to show the Notes, however the new line feed characters are not being shown, and the text is appearing as a giant blob.  Is there anyway to break on new line without changing the xsl I have here.  I have tried doing a find/replace for the \r and \n with the likes of

```
<br/>
```

and

```
&#10;
```

and

```
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
```

XSL:

```
 <td class="reportFieldData">
     <xsl:value-of select="LocationBasic/Notes"/>
 </td>
```

String Value of Notes:  "-- General Notes --\r\nThis location processes: All products.\r\n\r\n-- Policy Rules --\r\nPolicies beginning with"

How it Appears:

-- General Notes --This location processes: All products.-- Policy Rules --Policies beginning with

How I want it to Appear:

-- General Notes --

This location processes: All products.

-- Policy Rules --

Policies beginning with

Comment: Please post a [mcve] incl. a sample input.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I did include the input here, String Value of Notes: "-- General Notes --\r\nThis location processes: All products.\r\n\r\n-- Policy Rules --\r\nPolicies beginning with"

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question and add a [mcve] - that means a well-tormed XML document as the input, your current attempt as a full, executable XSLT stylesheet, and the exact code expected as the output.

Comment: Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the target format is HTML then using

```
<td class="reportFieldData">
     <pre>
        <xsl:value-of select="LocationBasic/Notes"/>
     </pre>
</td>
```

should be one way.

Comment: I would think that the purpose of the `class` attribute is to apply some styling to the `td` element. Using `pre` would defeat this.

Comment: Thanks Martin that seems to work, it now processes the line-breaks correctly.  However, there is an issue with the paragraphs, they do not break they are just one long line.  Is there away where I can keep the line-breaks but still have the text wrap for each paragraph.

Comment: In the end you need to find the right HTML and CSS combination for your needs, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space, perhaps `<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap;">` or `<pre style="white-space: pre-line;">` are more to your expectations. On the other hand, if you already have a CSS class for the whole `td` and the default behaviour of the HTML `pre` doesn't do what you think, you can of course also choose to put the CSS you want into the style rules for e.g. `.reportFieldData { white-space: pre-wrap; }` and then you don't need the `pre` wrapper at all.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that worked great!  I ended up using this to get the desired effect.  
            <td class="reportFieldData" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
              <xsl:value-of select="LocationBasic/Notes"/>
            </td>